# Using OnTouchListener creates Multiple Instances While OnClickListener Creates None

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I am trying to call the `PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder` for Google Places.

When I use

```
myTextField.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startPlaceLookup();
            }
        });
    }
```

No Instance is created and the intent is never fired.

When I use

```
myTextField.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                startPlaceLookup();
                return false; //OR TRUE
            }
        });
```

Multiple intents (5-10) are created.

Here is how the Intent is created:

```
 private void startPlaceLookup() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Start Place Lookup");
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Trying Intent");
            Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN).build(NewCallActivity.this);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);

        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
```

***How can I get only once instance of the Places Builder to show up when the user touches the EditText field?***

Comment: Filter by their action, touch events will be fired for pressing and unpressing as well as dragging.

Comment: I like the coward down votes without any explanations.

Comment: Downvotes generally don't have to be explained, but sure, i'll explain mine since I was the one who did it - You did not do your homework aka the prerequisite research required; which would also lead you to your answer, much like Kevinrob told you in his answer.
So whenever you see a similar "coward downvote", please presume the reason is what i told you above (lack of research effort), as it well might be me again. I merely looked at your question, gave you a hint and downvoted since you could've done better.

Answer (score 0):

`OnTouchListener` will be called for each event (DOWN, MOVE, UP, etc...).
`OnClickListener` will be called when a "Touch" is detected (DOWN and UP, without a lot of move, ...)

`OnClickListener` is something that work out-of-the-box but can not working if you have an `OnTouchListener` or the view is disabled. What is `myTextField`?